# Free tier compute engine deploy is charging values on GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can i configure a free tier compute engine?

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it right. The instance will show on the billing as charged for, but it's deducted from the monthly bill if you did everything correctly. Just create the instance and check if Subtotal stays 0.00. The rest of the billing is irrelevant to you if you do not have any other resources.

To view the page I screencapped go to "View Detailed Charges" from the Dashboard of your project.

The link you shared has all the info you need to create the instance with the free "specs".

[image: My monthly bill]

Comment: 1st time, you want to try free VM, it is scary to see non null estimation

Comment: View Detailed Charges ... where is it nowadays, I can not find it ?

Comment: It's still there, go to your dashboard, https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard then it's on the bottom of the "Billing" tile. (if you don't have a billing tile, you can add it using the "CUSTOMISE" button top right.